# Linear Layout can not type cast to Keyword Layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am having one LinnearLayout and one Keyword layout. I want to type cast Linearlayout to Keyword layout but It gives exception.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to com.codiant.prortc.rtc.KeywordView
```

I want to use the object reference of Linearlayout. I am posting the code of activity where I implement code .

```
try {
            mKeywordView = (KeywordView) getContnetView();
            mKeywordView.setListner(new KeywordView.KeyboardListner() {
                @Override
                public void onVisbile(boolean isVisibile) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + isVisibile, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }catch (ClassCastException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: "+e);
        }
```

keywordChatView.java

This is KeywordChatView class

```
public class KeywordView extends LinearLayout {
    private  KeyboardListner mListner;

    public void setListner(KeyboardListner listner) {
        mListner = listner;
    }

    public KeywordView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public KeywordView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public KeywordView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public KeywordView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean b, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Log.d("Search Layout", "Handling Keyboard Window shown");

        final int proposedheight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        final int actualHeight = getHeight();

        if (actualHeight > proposedheight){
            // Keyboard is shown
            mListner.onVisbile(true);
        } else {
            // Keyboard is hidden
            mListner.onVisbile(false);
        }
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
    public  interface KeyboardListner
    {
        public  void onVisbile(boolean isVisibile);

    }

}
```

this is Linearlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout1"
    android:weightSum="1"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.codiant.prortc.PrivateChatActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/private_activity_chat">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/close_fl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".3"></FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_fl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".7"
        android:background="#800b0b0b">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_30"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Private Chat" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/close_iv"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_close" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/chat_rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_5"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_5"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_40" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_5"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/chat_et"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_40"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp_5"
                android:layout_weight=".9"
                android:background="@drawable/circluar_border" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_40"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_weight=".1">

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/send_fab"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
                    app:backgroundTint="@color/blue_500"
                    app:borderWidth="0dp"
                    app:elevation="6dp" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can take  KeywordView  mKeywordView instend of  LinearLayout mKeywordView both will work same.

Comment: Thank u  but I do  want to do  this , because I want generic solution which I can use in future with other project

Comment: okay i'll also search for this if i will found any answer then will tell you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inheritance works in the opposite direction than you have written. You can set `KeywordView` to the variable of `LinearLayout`, but not vice-versa.

Comment: Please explain , what do you mean by opposite direction

Comment: The current hierarchy of `KeywordView` is follow (left is more basic parent):
`View -> ViewGroup -> LinearLayout -> KeywordView`

So correct assignment will be next:
`final LinearLayout layout = (KeywordView) findViewById(R.id.keywordView);`

But you have wrong assignment:
`final KeywordView view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);`

Because of you try to assign parent class to the inheritor.

Answer (score 0):

You have object of type of LinearLayout ( as specified in XML ) and it can not be cast  to its Subclass.   Specify proper layout in your XML

Comment: any reason why it can not cast

Comment: Java object to be cast to another class,  has to be of that class  ( like, if you have ArrayList,  and List typed  reference you can cast to ArrayList )  But If you have ArrayList  and Collection reference you can not cast it to Map

Answer (score 0):

So you need to convert your `XML linear layout` to your `KeywordView` then you can do what you task.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packagename.KeywordView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout1"
    android:weightSum="1"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.codiant.prortc.PrivateChatActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/private_activity_chat">
</packagename.KeywordView >
```